# Align one view horizontally to the middle of the screen in an HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have the Text "2" aligned just were the vertical black line is:
[image]

I have an HStack with three elements. I want the first element to be on the leading edge, the second element centered, and the third element on the trailing edge.

The code I have tried is this:

```
VStack(alignment: .middle) {
    HStack {
        Text("1")
        Spacer()
        Text("2")
            .alignmentGuide(.middle) { d in
                d[VerticalAlignment.center]
            }
        Spacer()
        Text("Some more text")
    }
    .background(.red)
    .padding()
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(.blue)
```

And the custom HorizontalAlignment I use is this:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    enum Middle: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            context[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }

    static let middle = HorizontalAlignment(Middle.self)
}
```

However, this does not create the desired alignment effect.

How could I have the text "2" centered in the middle of the screen while the other views are leading and trailing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use max width of both left and right Texts, which will result in an equal distribution of space between them and still leave the middle Text out:

```
HStack {
    Text("1")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    Text("2")
    Text("Some more text")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. So simple!